# calculate derivative of time series

Tags: r, time-series

I'd like to calculate 1st and 2nd order derivative of time series, how can I achieve this in R.

```
 dput(ps)
structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "", index = structure(c(1409522400, 
1409523300, 1409524200, 1409525100, 1409526000, 1409526900, 1409527800, 
1409528700, 1409529600, 1409530500, 1409531400, 1409532300, 1409533200, 
1409534100, 1409535000, 1409535900, 1409536800, 1409537700, 1409538600, 
1409539500, 1409540400, 1409541300, 1409542200, 1409543100), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(24L, 1L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This calculates a spline and then takes the first derivative of it:

```
tt <- time(ps)
xts(splinefun(tt, ps)(tt, 1), tt)
```

Replace 1 with 2 to get second derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Since these are evenly spaced at 15-minute intervals,

```
d <- as.numeric(diff(ps))/15
```

gives you the change per minute; `diff(d)/15` should give you the second derivative (in units of minutes^(-2))

You can also use `diff(ps,differences=2)` to get second differences (which you can convert to derivatives by dividing by 225 ...)